# how can i get the row and the colum of a string in a text file? c#

Tags: c#, file-io

The text file i have contains this text:

```
ds
f
s df
sag
fd
g fd
g
tr
g
er perro muerto warwsad
wre
twerwetret reterts
sdfsdfwee werwerwer
a
e
i
o
u
aeiou
asd
ap
ad
asdre
```

and a want to find "asd" 
the output would be Column 0 Row 19

Comment: make two-diamential array with the maximums words in single line,and find the number of rows in your document.then make the array length with it,store all words according to it and then give the result using that array.

Comment: Please post the code you've tried. Your question sounds like u just want someone to write it for you

Comment: Read file line by line and keep track of the current row number. Inside each row do row.IndexOf(searchText) and if it is greater than -1 return row number and value of IndexOf

Answer (score 2):

If you're searching for an exact match on the entire line, then the column will always be 0 and you can find the first matching row with a simple LINQ statement:

```
var row = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\file.txt").ToList().FindIndex(x => x == "asd");
```

If you want to find all matching rows, look at `FindAll` instead of `FindIndex`.

If you want any line that *contains* the search term:

```
var allLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\myFile.txt").ToList();
var row = allLines.FindIndex(x => x.Contains("asd"));
var col = allLines[row].IndexOf("asd");
```

If the search word could occur anywhere in the string but it must be a whole word, try this (untested):

```
var allLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\myFile.txt").ToList();
var row = allLines.FindIndex(x => x.Split(' ').Contains("asd"));
var col = allLines[row].IndexOf("asd");
```

Beyond that, I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve, so one of these may work for you, or you may have to mix and match.

Answer (score 0):

@Grant gave a great answer but not most efficient I think, because of possible multiple iterations. You can do it in one:

```
var searchText = "asd";
var allLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\myFile.txt");
for (var i = 0; i < allLines.Length; i++)
{
    int j = -1;
    do 
    {
        j = allLines[i].IndexOf(searchText, j + 1);
        if (j >= 0)
            Console.WriteLine("Found '{0}' at {1} row in {2} column", searchText, i, j);
    } while (j >= 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work;

```
    private void SearchString(string searchTerm)
    {
        if (searchTerm.Length <= 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Search term must be atleast a character long.");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            string[] rows = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Aviral Singh\Desktop\Test.txt");
            int counter = 0;
            foreach (string row in rows)
            {
                if (row == searchTerm)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Search term '{0}' was found at row {1} and column {2}.", searchTerm, row.IndexOf(searchTerm), counter));
                }
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
```